# Python Regex doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, regex, rss

i've crafted this **regular expression**:

```
<entry>\\n<(\w+)>(.+?)</\w+>\\n</entry>
```

to parse the following **RSS Feed**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<feed version="0.3" xmlns="http://purl.org/atom/ns#">\n<title>Gmail - Inbox for g.bargelli@gmail.com</title>\n<tagline>New messages in your Gmail Inbox</tagline>\n<fullcount>2</fullcount>\n<link rel="alternate" href="http://mail.google.com/mail" type="text/html" />\n<modified>2011-03-15T11:07:48Z</modified>\n<entry>\n<title>con due mail...</title>\n<summary>Gianluca Bargelli http://about.me/proudlygeek/bio</summary>\n<link rel="alternate" href="http://mail.google.com/mail?account_id=g.bargelli@gmail.com&amp;message_id=12eb9332c2c1fa27&amp;view=conv&amp;extsrc=atom" type="text/html" />\n<modified>2011-03-15T11:07:42Z</modified>\n<issued>2011-03-15T11:07:42Z</issued>\n<id>tag:gmail.google.com,2004:1363345158434847271</id>\n<author>\n<name>me</name>\n<email>g.bargelli@gmail.com</email>\n</author>\n</entry>\n<entry>\n<title>test nuova mail</title>\n<summary>Gianluca Bargelli sono tornato!?& http://about.me/proudlygeek/bio</summary>\n<link rel="alternate" href="http://mail.google.com/mail?account_id=g.bargelli@gmail.com&amp;message_id=12eb93140d9f7627&amp;view=conv&amp;extsrc=atom" type="text/html" />\n<modified>2011-03-15T11:05:36Z</modified>\n<issued>2011-03-15T11:05:36Z</issued>\n<id>tag:gmail.google.com,2004:1363345026546890279</id>\n<author>\n<name>me</name>\n<email>g.bargelli@gmail.com</email>\n</author>\n</entry>\n</feed>\n'skinner.com/products/spl].
```

The problem is that i am not getting any matches by using **Python's re module**:

```
import re

regex = re.compile("""<entry>\\n<(\w+)>(.+?)</\w+>\\n</entry>""")
regex.findall(rss_string) # Returns an empty list
```

Using an online regex tester (such as [this](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)) works as expected, so i don't think is a regex problem.

## Edit

I am well aware that **[using regular expressions to parse a Context-Free Grammar is BAD](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)**, but in my case the regular expression is likely to work **only** for that RSS feed (it is a Gmail inbox feed, by the way) and i know i can use an external library/xml parser for this task: it is only an **exercise**, not an **habit**.

The question should be **Why the following regular expression don't work as expected in Python?**

Comment: why are you using regex if python has an xml module made for exactly that?

Comment: Hi, i am aware of xmlparser but i was doing this as a regex exercise. I am also aware on the dangers on using RegEx on a context-free grammar: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: I wouldn't use an xml for that, regex means regular expression, it means regexes excel at being used on something regular. XML isn't regular. There is a lot to account for in an xml file, if a regex works for one it doesn't mean it will work for the next one.

Comment: Well it was *intended* to work with only that rss feed i gave you, so where's the danger?

Comment: no danger at all, just want to keep you from trying to parse xml with regexes all the time ;) no worries.

Comment: ;-) i'm making an update to clarify this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before the regex compiler sees a string, Python has already processed the slash-escapes, therefore you'd have to escape it twice (e.g. `\\\\n` for `\\n`).  However, Python has a handy notation for exactly this sort of thing, just stick an `r` before the string:

```
regex = re.compile(r"""<entry>\\n<(\w+)>(.+?)</\w+>\\n</entry>""")
```

By the way, I agree with the others here, do not use regexes to parse XML.  However, hopefully you will find this string notation helpful in future regular expressions.

Comment: +1 I just tested this under Python 3.0.1 and it works just fine.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't parse XML with regex, instead you should use the [Universal Feed Parser](http://www.feedparser.org/) for Python. Using this library over regex will make your life easier and has been battle tested to be correct.

I personally have used this library many times, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

DON'T PARSE XML/HTML WITH REGEX!

Use one of the following:

- [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)
- [lxml](http://lxml.de/)
- [pyquery](http://packages.python.org/pyquery/)

Enjoy!

EDIT: Oh yeah it's RSS.  What the other people said... I'll be here all week.

Answer (score 1):

Do not try to reinvent wheels or playing the smart RSS parser guy. Reuse existing modules: http://www.feedparser.org/